# The difference between res.download() and createReadStream() in downloading files

Tags: node.js, express, download

I learned two ways of downloading files in node js and express, but I couldn't find out what the difference between them is: `res.download(path)` and `createReadStream(path)`.

I know that `createReadStream()` is creating a stream to know overflow the server and it's good way, but what about the other one?

These are the two examples:

```
const orderId = req.params.orderId;
const invoiceName = 'invoice-' + orderId + '.pdf';
const invoicePath = path.join('data', 'invoices', invoiceName)

res.download(invoicePath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
});
```

and

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(invoicePath);

res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Dispoition', 'attachment; filename=' + invoiceName);

readStream
    .on('open', function () {
      // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
      readStream.pipe(res);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      readStream.unpipe(res);
      console.log('All the data in the file has been read');
    })
    .on('close', function (err) {
      console.log('Stream has been Closed');
      next(err)
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly looking at express *res.download()* source code, it essentially automates what you are doing manually with the alternative example. This includes relying on streams for efficient transfer and minimizing memory footprint.

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js

It actually ends up calling the *sendfile()* function defined at line 1016 - which ends up calling *file.pipe(res)*.